# What's the difference between `ConstantInt::getTrue (LLVMContext &Context)` and `ConstantInt::getTrue (Type *Ty)`?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I found 2 APIs in `llvm::ConstantInt` document:

1. `static ConstantInt *ConstantInt::getTrue (LLVMContext &Context)`: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a82dbbd8e3688b0bc1eedb338864d0d0c
2. `static Constant *ConstantInt::getTrue (Type *Ty)`: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a1d728e83e9e0fa85b0b58b33ec9c3197

But I don't know what's the difference between these 2 APIs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former constructs a `ConstantInt` which has `i1` type, while the latter allows you to specify the type yourself. This might be useful to construct `i8 0`, `i16 1` and like that.